# show that M[X] is an R[X]-module.

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

Let $M$ be an $R$-module and let $M[X]$ be the set of polynomials in $X$ with coefficients in $M$.

using the fact that $M[X]$ is an $R$-module with the obvious addition and scalar multiplication.

Defining the product of an element of $R[X]$ and an element of $M[X]$ in the obvious way, show that $M[X]$ is an $R[X]$-module.

Comment: What have you tried? There's not a lot to do here, except multiply and add formal expressions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a general fact, that if $R \le S$ are rings and $M$ is an $R$-module, then $S \otimes_R M$ is a $S$-module (the *induced module*). In your case  $M[X] = R[X] \otimes_R M$ is an $R[X]$-module.